# Forecasting with tsDyn - Error in R

Tags: r, neural-network, forecasting

Good morning,
I am currently using a time series of daily sales to make forecasting.
 
The dataset, called `myts` has previously been transformed into `time series` object.

Whenever I run the following code, it gives me an **error**:

```
require(tsDyn)
x <- log(myts)
mod.ar <- linear(x, m=2)
```

> Error: `x` must be a vector, not a ts object, do you want
>   `stats::lag()`?

Best regards,
Alex

Answer (score 2):

The problem reported by Alessandro can be generated by the `lag` function of `dplyr` which overrides the `lag` function of `stats`.
Try this:

```
detach("package:dplyr", unload=TRUE)
library(tsDyn)
linear(log(lynx), m=2)
```

Here `linear` works correctly giving:

```
Non linear autoregressive model

AR model
Coefficients:
     const      phi.1      phi.2 
 2.4352150  1.3842377 -0.7477757
```

Now, try this:

```
detach("package:tsDyn", unload=TRUE)
library(dplyr)
library(tsDyn)
linear(log(lynx), m=2)
```

The code gives the error message:

```
Error: `x` must be a vector, not a ts object, do you want `stats::lag()`?
```

Comment: Excellent finding Marco!

Answer (score 1):

Try this example (notice that I start with a vector and then convert it to a time series object)

```
require(tsDyn)

set.seed(1234)
tsdatav <- (seq(1:300)+rnorm(300,1000,10))
myts <- ts(tsdatav, frequency = 365, start = c(2017, 6))
plot(myts)

x <- log(myts)
mod.ar <- linear(x, m = 2)
mod.ar
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem is caused by `dplyr` having its own version of `lag`, which overrides the usual lag function, as well as a mistake in the way package `tseriesChaos` (which `tsDyn` depends on) imports stas::lag. A fix has been sent and approved, but not yet submitted to CRAN:
https://github.com/antoniofabio/tseriesChaos/commit/8abcc5a2d6d65588cdcec5527d4e5cb96eeccaec

In the meanwhile, you can simply overwrite `lag` back:

```
lag <- stats::lag
```

This should now work:

```
mod.ar <- linear(lynx, m=2)
```

And if you really want `dplyr`'s version, use `dplyr::lag`
`